# Find the parent key value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays. I need to find the key value of fips == 1003 for example so I can add more information to that particular array. I've tried to read about array_search and get it to work but it doesn't seem to return anything I can use. As well as array_filter.

I really need to be able to do this again and again as I am running a for each over another dataset that has the fips codes in it and need to append that information to this array to use one big data set for this application I am trying to write.

```
array(10) {
  [2006]=>
  array(3143) {
    [0]=>
     array(4) {
      ["fips"]=>
       string(4) "1001"
       ["county"]=>
      string(14) "Autauga County"
      ["state"]=>
      string(2) "AL"
      ["pop"]=>
      string(5) "54571"
    }
    [1]=>
     array(4) {
      ["fips"]=>
      string(4) "1003"
      ["county"]=>
      string(14) "Baldwin County"
      ["state"]=>
      string(2) "AL"
      ["pop"]=>
      string(6) "182265"
    }
    [2]=>
     array(4) {
      ["fips"]=>
      string(4) "1005"
      ["county"]=>
      string(14) "Barbour County"
      ["state"]=>
      string(2) "AL"
      ["pop"]=>
      string(5) "27457"
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this with `array_search`, it's for matching elements of 1-dimensional arrays. If you need to do this a lot, you should make an associative array whose keys are the `fips` values and values are the indexes into this array.

Comment: I actually just figured out how to do it with array_search(); I wasn't thinking that it was 2 levels deep and so I put it in like

    $key = array_search('1003', array_column($dataArray1[2006], 'fips'));

And it worked.

Comment: @TimHerbert The solution you figured out is related to the suggestions by @Barmar - it makes a single-dimensional array which can be easily searched. Note that array_column  is an expensive operation, so if you're not adding new fips values in the process, you probably want to make a `$lookupArray = array_column($dataArray1[2006], 'fips')` once and then `$key = array_search('1003', $lookupArray)` in your loop...

Comment: @TimHerbert Can you really hard-code `1003` and `2006` like that? I assumed you needed a more general solution, so my answer gets all the indexes from the multidimensional array.

Comment: Well I am not hard coding the 1003 and 2006. I just don't have those variables defined for this question and so it was easier to hard code them for the example. I am actually using years for 2006 and fips codes for the 1003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an associative array whose keys are the `fips` values, and values are the indexes into this array.

```
$index_array = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $j => $element) {
        $index_array[$element['fips']] = array($i, $j);
    }
}
```

Then when you're processing the other dataset, and you have a `$fips` value, you can do:

```
$indexes = $index_array[$fips];
$array[$indexes[0]][$indexes[1]]['new_field'] = $new_field_value;
```